# && and || in while loops

Tags: swift, while-loop

Hi I have small problem with this challenge:

Given a number between 2 and 12, calculate the odds of rolling this number using two six-sided dice. Compute it by exhaustively looping through all of the combinations and counting the fraction of outcomes that give you that value. Don't use a formula.

My solution is:

```
let givenNumber = 10
var cube1 = 1
var cube2 = 1
var count = 0
let allCombinations = 36

while (cube1 != 6 || cube2 != 6) {

    if cube1 + cube2 == givenNumber {
        count += 1
    }

    if cube1 != 6 {
        cube1 += 1
    } else {
       cube1 = 1
        cube2 += 1
    }
}

let probability = Double(count) / Double(allCombinations)
print(probability)
```

It works but I don't understand why :) becouse I belive it should be:

```
while (cube1 != 6 && cube2 != 6)
```

I want that this loop is repeated as long as cube1 and cube2 are not equal to 6 (not sure if that is correct in English gramma, but I hope you known what I mean), when both cube1 and cube2 are equal to 6 it should stop. But it stops when only cube1 is equal to 6. I thought it will do this with || :/.

Becouse I didn't understand it I did this different:

```
 let givenNumber = 10
    var cube1 = 1
    var cube2 = 1
    var count = 0
    let allCombinations = 36

    while true {

    if cube1 + cube2 == givenNumber {
        count += 1
    }

    if cube1 != 6 {
        cube1 += 1
    } else {
       cube1 = 1
        cube2 += 1
    }

    if cube1 == 6 && cube2 == 6 {
    break
   }
}

let probability = Double(count) / Double(allCombinations)
print(probability)
```

And it is ok, but maybe you can explain me why I'm wrong with this "while && / ||"?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using nested `for` loops.  `for cube1 in 1...6 { for cube2 in 1...6 { if cube1 + cube2 == ... } }`.

Comment: It is challenge from swift course book and `for` loops are in the next chapter :)

Comment: Ah OK.  Trust me, you're going to love them. ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basic logic, let me show you where you went wrong. This

> I want that this loop is repeated as long as cube1 and cube2 are not equal to 6

translates to `!(cube1 == 6 && cube2 == 6)` and **not** `(cube1 != 6 && cube2 != 6)`.

The former can be reduced using [logic formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) (De Morgan's laws) to get your original expression:

```
!(cube1 == 6 && cube2 == 6)
!(cube1 == 6) || !(cube2 == 6)
cube1 != 6 || cube2 != 6
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit of natural language explanation to maraca's answer (which is absolutely correct, consider my answer just as an extension of his answer):

```
while (cube1 != 6 && cube2 != 6)
```

means "do it while both of these conditions are true", so the evaluation will stop once *any* of the two is false. I.e. when `cube1` will reach `6` for the first time.

On the other hand

```
while (cube1 != 6 || cube2 != 6)
```

means: while any of these two is true, keep going. We can rephrase it as "stop only when both of these are false", which is "stop, when both `cube1` and `cube2` have reached `6`", which is exactly what we need.

Comment: Right, language is very important in my opinion, rephrasing questions or problems can be the first step to a solution.

Comment: Um.  Doesn't the second one mean while any of these two is **true** keep going?  You stop when they are both false, i.e. when both cube1 and cube 2 are 6.

Comment: @vacawama, thank you! I was confused because of `!=`. In my head it sounded like "while `cube1 is equal to 6` is false", so, due to a double negative, I mixed up `true` / `false` in the second part of the answer. I really appreciate pointing this out, I've edited the answer.